# Algorithms used in Android's Accessibility Colour Correction

Tags: accessibility, color

Since Android 5.0 there is an accessibility feature that allows the recolouring of everything that is displayed called [Colour Correction](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151850). This is meant to help people with impaired colour vision.

But how exactly are those options remapping the colours? 
Is there any information about which algorithms are used?